# how to load picture to server using iqengines api

Tags: java, android, image-recognition

I am trying to recognize pictures with IQ Engines, and can't upload picture. Have anyone practice with using this api, or any ather to recognize pictures? I tryed to load bitmap, use Base64, load link to picture, but haven't always get img-this field is required. the last example of code is

```
    public void postData() {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://api.iqengines.com/v1.2/query/");
    MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(
            HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

    File file = new File(path);

    try {
        // Add your data

        String time = myTime();
        String m = "api_key" + apiKey + "img" + file.getPath() + "json1"
                + "time_stamp" + time;

        try {
            sign = HmacSha1Signature.calculateRFC2104HMAC(m, secret);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SignatureException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        entity.addPart("api_key", new StringBody(apiKey));
        entity.addPart("api_sig", new StringBody(sign));
        entity.addPart("time_stamp", new StringBody(time));
        entity.addPart("json", new StringBody("1"));
        entity.addPart("img", new FileBody(file));
        httppost.setEntity(entity);

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        HttpEntity entity1 = response.getEntity();
        String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity1);
        tv.setText(result);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}
```

can anyone tell how it must be, or give working example of any other free api image recognition on android?